# Extend HashMap to implement custom remove()

Tags: java, android, iterator, overriding, class-extensions

I tried to extend the `HashMap` class to implement a custom `remove()` method, like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
private final class EntryHashMap<K, E> extends HashMap<K, E> {

    @Override
    public E remove(Object key) {
        rowKeyMap.remove(key);
        colKeyMap.remove(key);
        return super.remove(key);
    }

}
```

It all works well if  `remove()` is invoked directly, but when an iterator is used to remove the entry, the `remove()` method of `HashMap` is invoked instead of the above overriden `remove()` method:

```
public boolean selectiveRemove(Object key) {
    boolean result = false;
    Iterator<Entry<K, E>> it = entrySet().iterator();
    while( it.hasNext() ) {
        Entry<K, E> entry = it.next();
        K rowKey = entry.getKey();
        if( Utils.equals(key, rowKey) ) {
            it.remove(); // <<<<< this does not invoke the new `remove()`
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

After looking at the [*source code*](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/HashMap.java#HashMap.EntryIterator) for `HashMap` in the entry iterator I see:

```
private abstract class HashIterator {
    . . .

    public boolean hasNext() {
        . . .
    }

    HashMapEntry<K, V> nextEntry() {
        . . .
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (lastEntryReturned == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        HashMap.this.remove(lastEntryReturned.key); // <<< Hard coded call to HashMap's remove()
        lastEntryReturned = null;
        expectedModCount = modCount;
    }
}

private final class EntryIterator extends HashIterator
        implements Iterator<Entry<K, V>> {
    public Entry<K, V> next() { return nextEntry(); }
}
```

Extended `HashMap` classes do not have access to all private fields, so I cannot just modify the iterator, I would have to rewrite a lot of code to get my own iterator override that iterator.

**Is there a way to completely override `remove()` so it gets called in every situation where `HashMap.remove()` was called?**

Comment: Just a thought when seeing rows and columns - maybe guava's Table does what you need.

Comment: @assylias Yes, maybe, but that's a big change in my code I prefer to first try and resolve the bug issues.

Comment: To start with you should not extend `HashMap`; if you really need a custom implementation, extend `AbstractMap` instead.

Comment: @fge Why I should not extend `HashMap`? If the class is not meant to be extended it would have been `final`

Comment: Just an example: `.removeAll()`. Nothing guarantees you that it will call `.remove()` if you just override `.remove()`! Another solution is to use delegation, or arrange for creating a class which does not require you to extend a map implementation in the first place

Comment: @fge I want my `remove()` to be called only if the original `remove()` was called. If `removeAll()` calls `HashMap.remove()` I want,it to call my `remove()` instead. I think this is what overriding is for.

Comment: You didn't understand. What if `HashMap`'s `.removeAll()` _does not_ call `.remove()`?

Comment: @fge If if HashMap's `.removeAll()` does not call `.remove()` it is fine, I don't want it call my new `.remove()` either.